# How to share data with socket.io instances on windows azure

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, socket.io, azureservicebus

I am using the brilliant [socket.io-servicebus](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/socket.io-servicebus) for scaling my socket.io server. With this library whenever I emit some data from one socket.io instance it is sent to all clients irrespective of which socket.io instance they are connected to. But I also want to share some state values with other socket.io instances whenever this data is sent across to all connected clients. How can i do it using socket.io ? As in can i use some events to which i will send this state information from one socket.io instance and all the other socket.io instances could be listening on it.

To put it simply, is there any way i can send data from one socket.io instance to other socket.io instances?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using Service Bus as the backplane for sharing socket.io traffic between nodes. From a scale perspective Service Bus Topics can handle messages from any number of different input streams so they do not have to be from the same socket.io stream. So essentially you could just use the same Service Bus Namespace and Topic name for both the Socket.io streams and all the traffic will be exchanged between them. Should be a fun experiment since I do not think we tried this scenario :)